# Serving image with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a program which generates an image. Now I want to use Flask to make this picture accessible to other users, but I can’t display this image with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
#coding: utf-8

from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

#app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

My template hello.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<img src="./weather-plot.png">
```

When I run this program and visit the page, I see this:

```
192.168.0.61 - - [10/Jul/2013 10:22:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.61 - - [10/Jul/2013 10:22:09] "GET /weather-plot.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And in my browser I see the title, but not the picture. What’s wrong?

By the way, is there a better method to display a picture without anything else? Maybe I don’t have to use a template?

Comment: Uhm, I think the title tag is missplaced. It is a part of the header and not of the body section.

Comment: @reporter: The _tags_ for the `head` and `body` elements are optional, so there's nothing wrong with the HTML above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure the image is indeed in the location `./`, i.e. in the root of your project?
In any case, it is better to use Flask's `url_for()` method to determine URLs (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) This makes sure that when you move things around, the URLs don't break.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I’ve used the `url_for` method and it has help me.